# Postgres Lateral Unnest - At Least 1 Value?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with an optional `fields` column of type `jsonb[]`. I am using a lateral unnest to break those fields out into rows, then an aggregate to combine them again in the order I want.

```
SELECT id, name, ARRAY_AGG(v ORDER BY v->'priority' DESC) as fields
FROM results, LATERAL UNNEST(fields) AS f(v)
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

But because `fields` is optional, not all rows have values to unnest to begin with. Is there a way to lateral unnest **at least** one row even if it is empty? Or is there a better way to apply an order to a `jsonb[]` column on the way out so I can avoid this lateral unnest all together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a `left join lateral`.

```
SELECT 
    id
  , name
  , ARRAY_AGG(v ORDER BY v->'priority' DESC) as fields
FROM results
LEFT JOIN LATERAL UNNEST(fields) AS f(v) ON TRUE
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I was looking for. Updated my original to remove the `3`